# Deploying SSDT project through Powershell Script: Version store out of memory error

Tags: sql-server, powershell, sql-server-2012, sql-server-data-tools, dacpac

Hoping someone may be able to advise what might be happening here.
I am attempting to run an SSDT deployment via a Powershell script directly on the SQL Server its-self.

SQL Version: 2012 (upgrade not possible at the moment)

Exact error:

> System.Management.Automation.MethodInvocationException:  Exception
>   calling "GenerateDeployScript" with "3" argument(s): "Version store
>   out of memory (cleanup already attempted)"
>   Microsoft.Isam.Esent.Interop.EsentVersionStoreOutOfMemoryException:
>   Version store out of memory (cleanup already attempted)

All my research on the web has solutions for when this occurs through MSBuild, however I have no-where to apply the fix for this process as it happens outside of the build process.

Can anyone advise how one might prevent this from occuring?
Thanks :)

Comment: @Avshalom thanks for the highlighting :)

Answer (score 0):

Try building with the MSBuild argument `/p:CmdLineInMemoryStorage=true`. This seems to have fixed this same issue for others running into this problem.

I have implemented the fix in my Azure DevOps Pipeline build for a database process that has also randomly had this error, and so far it seems to be working.

See also:

[SO question: DB Schema Compare Error: 'Version Store Out of Memory'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26511426/db-schema-compare-error-version-store-out-of-memory)